# "it rains something" - is it an idiom and when is it used?

Tags: idioms

I think I heard somewhere expressions like "it rains apples" or "it rains ideas" which could possibly mean there is a lot of apples and ideas, but I am not sure. Is there anything like that in English?

Comment: It's an idiom and a metaphor.  Stuff is coming at you faster than you can deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rain?q=Rain).

It is used to convey that something is falling or happening in large or overwhelming quantities. 
Examples - The gunship rained bullets on to the terrorists. 
Bombs rained down.